# How can we efficiently generate Shapely polygons while excluding a set of points, and including a set of points?

Tags: python, optimization, shapely

I want to generate N polygons that should satisfy the following:

1. It must NOT include a set of points (at the maximum 50)
2. It MUST include a set of points (at the maximum 50)

My strategy is to create a polygon randomly and check if that polygon satisfy (1) and (2). Do the same for N=100 polygons. For adding 10 polygons, it takes about 1 min. This process is extremely time consuming. Is there any better way to handle it? It also depends on the mean and sigma of the Gaussian distribution, where I sample polygon location from.

Shapely version : 1.8.5.post1, Python3.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import random
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from shapely.geometry import box, Point
from descartes import PolygonPatch
from shapely import affinity

def create_center_origin_rectangle(object_center, deg, object_length=0.06):
    # find bottom left corner coordinate from center
    object_x_corner = object_center[0] - (object_length)/2.0
    object_y_corner = object_center[1] - (object_length)/2.0

    # add rectangle patch using bottom coordinates
    rectangle = patches.Rectangle((object_x_corner, object_y_corner), object_length, object_length,linewidth=1, edgecolor='none', facecolor='none', alpha=0.5)

    # get bottom left and bottom right coordinates from Rectangle()
    bottom_left = rectangle.get_xy()
    upper_right = (rectangle.get_x()+rectangle.get_width(), rectangle.get_y()+rectangle.get_height())

    # use bottom left and bottom right coordinates to create Shapely box
    polygon_box = box(bottom_left[0], bottom_left[1], upper_right[0], upper_right[1])
    polygon = affinity.rotate(polygon_box, deg)
    patch = PolygonPatch(polygon, facecolor='none', edgecolor='grey', alpha=0.3, zorder=-1)
    return patch, polygon

random.seed(100)
np.random.seed(100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-0.1,0.1)
ax.set_ylim(-0.1,0.1)

outside_points = np.asarray([(0.01,0.05), (0.023,0.06), (-0.03, 0.02), (-0.04, -0.02), (-0.03,-0.03), (0.012, -0.03)])
ax.plot(outside_points[:,0], outside_points[:,1], marker='*', linestyle='', color='black', label='outside points')

inside_points = np.asarray([(0.02, 0.04), (0.03, 0.03), (0.02,0.06)])
ax.plot(inside_points[:,0], inside_points[:,1], marker='*', linestyle='', color='red', label='inside points')

num_cube = 0

print "start time:", datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')

while num_cube < 10:
    inside_points_check = []
    outside_points_check = []

    cube_center_x = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.06)
    cube_center_y = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.06)
    deg = np.random.randint(0,359)
    patch_1, polygon_1 = create_center_origin_rectangle(object_center=(cube_center_x, cube_center_y), deg=deg)

    # condition 1: check if polygon does not contain all the OUTSIDE points
    for outside_point in outside_points:
        outside_points_check.append(polygon_1.contains(Point(outside_point[0], outside_point[1])))

    # condition 2: check if polygon contains all the INSIDE points
    for inside_point in inside_points:
        inside_points_check.append(polygon_1.contains(Point(inside_point[0], inside_point[1])))
    
    # satisfy both condtion 1 and condition 2
    if np.all(np.asarray(outside_points_check) == False) and np.all(np.asarray(inside_points_check) == True):
        num_cube += 1
        ax.add_patch(patch_1)

print "end time:", datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: the above code throws error `IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 2 were indexed` on line `patch = PolygonPatch(polygon, facecolor='none', edgecolor='grey', alpha=0.3, zorder=-1)`

Comment: shapely version used is 1.7.1, which requires descartes from https://github.com/benjimin/descartes Unfortunately I cannot upgrade shapely version, and I can only use python2.7

Comment: ok, you should definitely add the appropriate python version to tag list. I can't help you unfortunately, i'm on `3.10` and don't keep `2.7`.

Comment: Thank you. Anyway I updated the code to reflect Shapely 1.85 and python3.

Comment: so now you should get the above errror. Have you fixed it?

Comment: I do not get the error you mentioned with: Shapely 1.8.5 and python3. Maybe the issue is numpy or matplotlib version mismatch? My current version: numpy '1.19.5', matplotlib '3.3.4'

Comment: I have `numpy 1.24` and `matplotlib 3.5.1`

Comment: In pip3, the maximum available version is 1.19.5. Would it help, if I added the PolygonPatch source(with citation) as a part of my code?

Comment: Do you need rectangle like in your code or does any polygon suffice? For example, is a small buffer around a minimum spanning tree a solution? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree)

Comment: @VictorSavenije Thank you for introducing Minimum Spanning Tree. I did not know that a technique like that existed!